# PySide2: window is not responding

Tags: python, mouseevent, pyside2, pyautogui, python-3.8

[image: Problem]

Window is not responding when opened before the mouse.wait function.
If replace the mouse.wait function to another (which doesn't waiting the mouse click), the window will open normally.

```
import pyautogui, sys, mouse
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from design import Ui_Form, Ui_Next

def mpos(file):
    mouse.wait(button='right', target_types='down')
    x,y=pyautogui.position()
    file.write(str(x)+'_'+str(y)+'-')

def prog():
    with open('prog.txt', 'w') as file:
        next()
        mpos(file)
        next()
        mpos(file)
        next()
        mpos(file)

def menu():
    mui.configButton.clicked.connect(prog)
    wmenu.show()

def fclose():
    wnext.close()

def next():
    nui.okButton.clicked.connect(fclose)
    wnext.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

wmenu = QtWidgets.QFrame()
mui = Ui_Form()
mui.setupUi(wmenu)

wnext = QtWidgets.QFrame()
nui = Ui_Next()
nui.setupUi(wnext)

menu()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the wait method blocks the Qt event loop by freezing the GUI. A possible solution is to run it in another thread:

```py
import threading

# ...

def execute_thread():
    threading.Thread(target=prog, daemon=True).start()

def menu():
    mui.configButton.clicked.connect(execute_thread)

# ...
```